# Django channels Error when starting the server

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have my channels placed in the top of INSTALLED_APPS.

When I ty to start the server I get following error:

````
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    from channels import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'channels' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\channels\__init__.py)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just was Installing django_channels not right way.
I should install django_channels throught that way `python -m pip install -U channels`, Not throught `pip isnstall django_channels`.